# why unable to upload file using tftp?

Tags: c, freertos, tftp

Is it necessary to establish the connection each time during uploading the file in the multiple iteration for maintaining the stack size?

I got a calloc failed error.

I am using freertos with multithreading.

Comment: This is very difficult to understand what you're asking. Show some code and explain *exactly* what the problem is. There is no way we're going to be able to help if we don't know what your code is doing!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol), yes, TFTP does not allow keeping the connection alive for multiple files.

If you are working with a small embedded system, its filesystem might not be designed to handle many files (even small ones) and you would want to reorganize the data into fewer.

Not sure what this has to do with stack size or running out of heap space. The question is very vague but you might want to account for scarce memory resources (using pencil and paper, even) to plan how the program will run, and avoid chasing these bugs every time a new feature is added.